# Gatling. Live users. Remotely closed / Connection timeout

Tags: stress-testing, gatling

I'm trying to exec

```
scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(300) during (300 seconds) randomized),
```

When running, I get number of active users growing fast to around 2000.
Then connection either 'timeout' or 'remotely closed'

Few questions:

1. Why even though I define 300 users per second I have my 'active users' grow to 2k.
2. I'm testing it on local environment mostly to test MySQL database performance. But I guess it fails because of system requirements and/or configuration.

Anything I can do about it ?

Answer (score 0):

If your users don't terminate fast enough (long test journey, long response times), you'll get 2k concurrent users within 7 sec (2000 / 7).